# Limiting HTML picture grid columns

Tags: html, css, idocscript

I'm working on iDocScript and HTML to read on a picture database and return the result in a four column and unlimited rows picture grid.

[ picture ] [ picture ] [ picture ] [ picture ]

[ picture ] [ picture ] [ picture ] [ picture ]

Something like this and i'm confused to limit the number of columns even without using iDocScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use column-count to limit the number of column with an element like so :

```
.example {
  -webkit-columns: 4 150px;
  -moz-columns: 4 150px;
  columns: 4 150px;
  -webkit-column-gap: 2em;
  -moz-column-gap: 2em;
  column-gap: 2em;
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jeh5hwc5/)